# Converting Textfile from UTF-8 to Codepage 850

Tags: php, utf-8, converters, codepages

I have a PHP script which is writing some content to a text file.

I have a problem that involves the character set not being correct when the text file gets imported to the ERP.

**How can I include a conversion from UTF-8 to code page 850 in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'cp850//TRANSLIT', 'some text here');
```